# Windows is not showing up in boot menu after installing Pop_OS on a separate NVMe drive

Tags: windows, boot, grub, efi, pop-os

I have two NVMes on my laptop. I already have Windows 11 in one, and I wanted to install Pop_OS on the other.

After installing Pop_OS, it only showed Pop_OS in the boot menu after starting up the laptop. Even though I can access files from the other drive.

I tried to reinstall Pop_OS, but it gave me an error during the installation process. However the option for Pop_OS is still showing and it also seems to run fine. But the option for Windows still doesn't appear in the boot menu.

I have tried to 'add path location' for windows from BIOS, there's one file called bootmgrw.efi, but using that shows me an error that suggests to use the Windows installation CD and troubleshoot by selecting 'repair windows'. I've done that as well, but it also didn't work.

From a few other suggestions from another forum, I installed rEFind Boot Manager, although on system startup it shows a different screen with available boot options, but Windows still doesn't appear. I am a Linux Newbie and still learning, so I might've installed it incorrectly, I am not sure what I did wrong tho: I only had to install reFind while the other drive is mounted as well.

I'd really appreciate it some help and suggestions, thank you!

My System:

- Asus TUF Dash F15
- Two separate NVMes
- One has Windows 11
- The other has Pop_OS

Comment: Was Windows version Windows 11?  and did POP have all the attributes (UEFI, Secure Boot, TPMV2) to coexist with Windows 11?   If you are able to reset variables in BIOS (I am not certain - Secure Boot is the only BIOS setting I think), run POP as a virtual machine. Much safer.

Comment: If the above suggestion does not work, you may need to repair / reinstall Windows using the Windows ISO.  .....    I am a Linux Newbie and still learning   .... Most definitely use a virtual machine for this.   Posted from my Kali 2023.3 VM.

Comment: I posted an answer for you @ray_lv   .. This way when you install POP OS you will be able to run it and ensure it is correct.

Comment: do you think a solution might be possible [here](https://rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#linux)

Comment: My answer is what you need to - especially Part 1 - reinstall Windows

Comment: Can you clarify on what "boot menu" you are referring to (by attaching a photo, maybe)? If you can still boot to Pop, it might help clear things up by adding the output of `efibootmgr` and `lsblk -f` to your question. (Run them as root / with `sudo`, just in case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> error that suggests to use the Windows installation CD and
> troubleshoot by selecting 'repair windows'. I've done that as well,
> but it also didn't work.

**(1)** At this point, the only practical option you have is to back up whatever files you can   *(I can access files from the other drive)*  and then install Windows fresh.

Allow Windows to make its 3 partitions (EFI, Recovery, and Data).  Get Windows running properly and fully installed.

This will get Windows running properly

**(2)** Forget Dual Boot - it is not a good strategy for 95 % of users. Further, Dual Boot is a terrible way to learn another OS like Linux because of the common breakability often caused. In numerous cases, Dual Boot is very difficult to troubleshoot because you may not know where the error lies.

Dual Boot is not inherently safe.

**(3)** Get a good Virtual Machine App  (VMware Workstation is the best and most flexible overall) and install POP OS as a VM.  I have a POP OS VM on a backup drive on another computer, so what I as suggesting works fine.

Virtual Machines are vastly safer than Dual Boot.

Comment: I understand using a Virtual Machine is safe. But I thought installing Pop_OS on a separate harddrive from my Windows would be safer as well. I have read posts where they suggest as a good approach as well. Can you give an idea how could the windows partitions be deleted if they were on a separate drive from where the Pop was being installed?

Comment: No, I my view, Dual Boot is not safer as you have seen yourself. The partitions probably were not deleted - just damaged and not easily repairable . This approach is most definitely  not safer. Virtual Machines can easily be rebuilt without damaging the host. I have done this.

Comment: @ray_lv apart from "pebkac", many linux installers are dumb and sometimes flawed/buggy. The fact that you choose to install to one drive doesn't necessarily mean that it wouldn't mess with the other. Besides, sometimes it is indeed intentional. For example, in some peoples' opinion a machine should have one EFI system partition (ESP) in total, so the installer could end up trying to share Windows ESP. While this doesn't mean it's gonna ruin Windows Boot Manager, some UEFI firmware could be flawed / bugged as well, so it could end up stop detecting some path when new EFI executables are added.

Comment: I installed backed up my files and installed windows. Everything is fixed now, i.e. I can access both OS's. Thank you :D However, I still wish if there could've been a better way than than to lose all my files in order to fix such an issue.